# Pattern for month with low and capital letters

Tags: regex

I have following strings:

```
Emini Mar 15 ME 
Emini ICE MAR 15 RTA 
Emini ABC Apr 15 RTA
```

and use pattern:

```
[\S]*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jin|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)+(\s+\d{1,2})
```

How to create short pattern instead ...(Jan|JAN|jan|Feb|FEB|feb...) etc.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add case-insensitive modifier `i`

```
(?i)\S*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)+(\s+\d{1,2})
```